FeynRules error
I am trying to run a simple FeynRules calculation for a simple qed lagrangian. But I am getting errors. FeynRules don't have documentation of errors. The errors are:
PartClass::NoGenMatch: Number of particles does not match the number of Generations of the class.
LoadModel::FAMass: In FeynRules mode, all class members should be given a mass name.
The code goes as follows:
(***************** This is the FeynRules model file for QED ************************)
M$ModelName = "Prac";
M$Information = {Authors -> "Tahmeed",
Institutions -> "Dhaka University",
Emails -> "",
Date -> ""};
(***** Parameter list ******)
FR$RmDblExt = { yme -> Me,
ymm -> MMU, ymtau -> MTA};
M$Parameters = {
yme == {
ParameterType -> External,
BlockName     -> YUKAWA,
OrderBlock    -> 11,
Value         -> 5.11*^-4,
Description   -> "Electron Yukawa mass"},

ymm == {
ParameterType -> External,
BlockName     -> YUKAWA,
OrderBlock    -> 13,
Value         -> 0.10566,
Description   -> "Muon Yukawa mass"},

ymtau == {
ParameterType -> External,
BlockName     -> YUKAWA,
OrderBlock    -> 15,
Value         -> 1.777,
Description   -> "Tau Yukawa mass"
},

ee == { 
ParameterType    -> Internal, 
Value            -> Sqrt[4 Pi 0.00782], 
InteractionOrder -> {QED,1}, 
TeX              -> e,  
Description      -> "Electric coupling constant"

}
};
(***** Gauge group list ******)
M$GaugeGroups = {
U1Y  == {
Abelian          -> True,
CouplingConstant -> ee,
GaugeBoson       -> A,
Charge           -> Q
}
};
(***** Particle classes list ******)
M$ClassesDescription = {
F[1] == {
ClassName        -> l,
ClassMembers     -> {e, mu, ta},
SelfConjugate    -> False,
Mass             -> {Ml, {Me,5.11*^-4}, {MMU,0.10566}, {MTA,1.777}},
Width            -> 0,
ParticleName     -> {"e-", "mu-", "ta-"},
AntiParticleName -> {"e+", "mu+", "ta+"},
FullName         -> {"Electron", "Muon", "Tau"}
},
V[1] == {
ClassName       -> A,
SelfConjugate   -> True,
Unphysical      -> True,
Mass            -> 0,
Width           -> 0,
ParticleName    -> "a",
FullName        -> "Photon"
}
} ;

Implementation details of computational tasks are off-topic on this site: “While computational physics is on topic, we are not a programming site. If your question is about implementing computational code - in particular, if it's about writing, compiling, debugging or optimizing code, or about a specific language or library - then it is off topic.”

Since FeynRules is a Mathematica package, this question would be on-topic on [mathematica.se].
